# Use variables from other Vue instances and cross reference them

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 different parts of the website

**First**: is it ok to use one instance in another especially with `v-model`, is this have any disadvantages.

**Second**: Is there any way I can cross reference each other, like `footer` in `aside` even though one is declared before the other. I get an error with this code. `"footer is undefined"`

My JS:

```
var aside = new Vue({
    "el":"aside",
    data:{
        name:"Peylan"
    }
});
var footer= new Vue({
    "el":"footer",
    data:{
        companyname:"Company Inc"
    }
});
```

My HTML

```
<aside><h3 v-bind="footer.companyname"></h3></aside>
<footer>
    <input type="text" v-model="aside.name">
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way of handling what you want is using a shared Vuex store.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<aside><h3 v-text="footer.companyname"></h3></aside>
<footer>
    <input type="text" v-model="aside.name">
</footer>

<script>
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    strict: false,
    state: {
        aside: {
            name:"Peylan"
        },
        footer: {
            companyname:"Company Inc"
        }
    }
});
var aside = new Vue({
    store,
    "el":"aside",
    data:{},
    computed: {
        ...Vuex.mapState(['aside', 'footer'])
    }
});
var footer= new Vue({
    store,
    "el":"footer",
    data:{},
    computed: {
        ...Vuex.mapState(['aside', 'footer'])
    }
});
</script>
```

The demo above is a very simplified way of using it. For optimal usage (like with getters, actions and mutations) consider Vuex's official docs.

Or you can use a computed property on both, like below.

This creates a bit of a chicken and egg issue, that's why you need to use `.$mount()` in this case.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<aside><h3 v-text="footer.companyname"></h3>
</aside>
<footer>
    <input type="text" v-model="aside.name">
</footer>

<script>
var aside = new Vue({
    data:{
        name:"Peylan"
    },
    computed: {
        footer() { return footer; }
    }
});
var footer = new Vue({
    data:{
        companyname:"Company Inc"
    },
    computed: {
        aside() { return aside; }
    }
});
aside.$mount("aside");
footer.$mount("footer");
</script>
```